# Inheriting a Base Form but Paste/Cut Commands Not Captured

Tags: c#, vb.net, inheritance, richtextbox

I created a base form that has a specific size and an icon as a base for all forms created in my project (to be consistent in looks). The problem is, for some reason if I add a Text box to the Child form, I can no longer execute shortcuts like Copy (CTRL+C) etc into the Textbox.

What should I do to handle this OTHER THAN writing code to capture those on the KeyUp control?

This is also the case for RichTextBox control as well.

Thanks

Comment: I created another project to try to regenerate this issue and was not able to. This seems to be a bug in the control. I'll have to recreate everything from scratch and see if I'm getting the same issue. 
Thanks to everyone who attempted to fix this issue but it doesn't seem to happen anywhere except for my current project.

Comment: OK I finally figured it out! 
The reason CTRL+C (and the rest) were not executing their respective commands is because I started the project with an MDI Parent Form. 

MDI Parent form automatically populates several controls in which a menu item like Paste was under the Edit menu item. Paste was associated with the shortcut CTRL+V (again automatically by the MDI Parent form template). The problem was that menu item's Click event wasn't handled and therefore everytime I tried to click on CTRL+V in a RichTextBox or TextBox (or pretty much any editable form) it wasn't doing anything. YIKES!

Answer (score 0):

I am not able to replicate your problem. But I would suggest that is better to avoid inheritance, check [Microsoft Application Architecture Guide, 2nd Edition](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=ce40e4e1-9838-4c89-a197-a373b2a60df2&displaylang=en) for details

> **Prefer composition to inheritance.**
>   Wherever possible, use composition
>   over inheritance when reusing
>   functionality because inheritance
>   increases the dependency between
>   parent and child classes, thereby
>   limiting the reuse of child classes.
>   This also reduces the inheritance
>   hierarchies, which can become very
>   difficult to deal with.